# Server stucked in reboot

Tags: debian, fstab, reboot

When I reboot the server, it is getting stucked here.

It may have problem with this webdav mounting in fstab:

```
https://webdavdir /home/user/Maildir davfs rw,uid=user,gid=user,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 0 0
```

Any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Give your root password for maintenance and check the syslog. If you suspect your latest change is responsible, reverse it.

Comment: Usually the network is not present at this stage, you should try with `_netdev` option and see if it helps. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169697/how-does-netdev-mount-option-in-etc-fstab-work has some more information.

Comment: @eblock thx man.. I found the solution elsewhere but I am glad people like you are here to help :)

Answer (score 1):

solution:
added **_netdev**

```
https://webdavdir /home/user/Maildir davfs rw,_netdev,uid=user,gid=user,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 0 0
```